# What is a pythonic way to have property getters without setters with python dataclasses?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a situation where I need to store variables a,b, and c together in a dataclass, where `c = f(a,b)` and a,b can be mutated. I need `c` to be displayed along with a and b when printing the object, and `c` cannot be changed except through changing `a` or `b`.
I felt the best way to do this was to have `c` be a value created with a property.

Minimal example of what I tried to use:

```
@dataclass
class Demo:
    a:int
    b:int
    c:int = field(init=False)

    @property
    def c(self) -> int:
        return self.a * self.b
```

However, calling this results in `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. I suspect the code is trying to set c to `field(init=False)`, and failing because c doesn't have a setter.

Options I've considered (not counting alternatives I tried that makes the code crash in a different manner):

- not having `c` in init

  - doesn't display c in repr, fields, etc. , which causes further issues down the line
- having a `@c.setter` that does nothing

  - this technically works, but involves writing boilerplate code that seemingly does nothing.
  - having a function that never gets called explicitly by any code I write but makes the program break is removed feels dangerous and unclean.
  - I also want the program to crash instead of silently doing nothing if someone tries to modify c directly.
- as above, but use `sys._getframe().f_back.f_code` in the setter to raise an error if the caller is not `__init__` (function at endnote)

  - Is a Cpython implementation detail only.
  - Using functions that are marked as private is a bad idea, generally speaking.
- have Demo be immutable, have `c` be created in `__post_init__`, and use `dataclasses.replace` to modify a and b.

  - this works in a vacuum, but other uses of `Demo` (well, the actual thing, not the minimal example) require it to be mutable.

endnote:

```
    @c.setter
    def c(self, val):
        caller = sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name
        if caller != '__init__':
            raise ValueError # or some other error
```

Comment: Did you read this blog article already? https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/

Comment: Yes. I looked at that, but it requires me to pass in a default variable for c, and as far as I can tell requires a setter anyway. Useful, generally, but not for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `c` overwrites your field `c` -- the original `field` declaration is lost, including the `init=False`.

Try changing the order and using the `default=` parameter.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Demo:
    @property
    def c(self) -> int:
        return self.a * self.b

    a: int
    b: int
    c: int = field(init=False, default=c)


d = Demo(5, 10)
print(d)
d.a = 10
print(d)
d.c = 4  # generates an AttributeError
```

Output from Python 3.8.0:

```
Demo(a=5, b=10, c=50)
Demo(a=10, b=10, c=100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/home/rob/src/plot/dc.py", line 20, in <module>
    d.c = 4  # generates an AttributeError
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: This seems rather fragile. It's relying on the fact that, *currently*, with *this particular combination of settings*, `dataclasses` doesn't store the default value on the instance. That's undocumented and may change, particularly to resolve inconsistencies like that between the behavior of `callback: Callable[[int], int] = lambda x: x**2` and `callback: Callable[[int], int] = field(init=False, default=lambda x: x**2)`, where [only the first one currently works properly](https://ideone.com/M8DG2C). Also, I can't run mypy here, but I would expect mypy probably doesn't like this.

Comment: Anyway, if you're going to do this, you should probably put `compare=False` in the field definition, to avoid wasting time comparing and hashing a computed property whose value is determined by `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want `c` to be a computed property, then take out the `c` field entirely and just leave the property:

```
@dataclass
class Demo:
    a:int
    b:int

    @property
    def c(self) -> int:
        return self.a * self.b
```

Fields are for stored data, which `c` should not be.

If you want `c` to show up in `repr`, you'll have to write the `__repr__` method yourself. If later code needs `c` to show up in `fields`, then you probably need to rework your code at a deeper level, and possibly switch to something other than `dataclasses`.

Comment: Not a good option. As I said in the question I need c to be displayed along with a and b when printing the object. I'd rather not have to write a boilerplate repr for this, if I can get dataclass to automate it

Comment: @readerboy7: You're going to need to write that `__repr__`. Fields are a fundamentally different thing from what you're trying to do.